# Move from booted RAID to single drive

Tags: backup, raid, migration, etc

Have Ubuntu 22.04 server installed on RAID5. It boots from /. I'd like to move it to a new SSD single drive though. My thoughts to do this is:

1. Make a backup of / with some software on backup USBdevice. Not a disk image, but backup of everything.
2. Take those drives out and put in new SSD ddrive.
3. Install new ubuntu to SSD.
4. Connect backup from USBDevice
5. Boot with a LiveCD.
6. Restore all, but /etc directory.

Is that right?
Main reason, is I have multiple dockers, apps, etc... ton of customization I don't want to go through re-setting up. Esp the dockers as some are volumes some are mounts, etc...

Is there a better way?

Comment: I do not see any mention of a version of Ubuntu in your question. Trying to restored selective OS directories from a back up is not going to work. All you will end up with is a corrupted OS.

Comment: Updated that info. Ubuntu Server 22.04